# Groupby and ifelse or replace

Tags: r

I am trying to create a new column based on a condition, I tried several methods:

1.

```
score%>%
  group_by(CONM)%>%
  mutate(y=ifelse((lag(score$NI,1)<0 &lag(score$NI,2)<0),1,0))%>%
  ungroup()
```

This gets get error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `Y`.
x Input `Y` can't be recycled to size 7.
ℹ Input `Y` is `ifelse((lag(score$NI, 1) < 0 & lag(score$NI, 2) < 0), 1, 0)`.
ℹ Input `Y` must be size 7 or 1, not 64.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: CONM = "A & E PLASTIK PAK INC".
```

2. 

```
setDT(score)
score[,y:=ifelse((lag(score$NI,1)<0 &lag(score$NI,2)<0),1,0),by=CONM]
```

and get the error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(score, , `:=`(y, ifelse((lag(score$NI, 1) < 0 &  : 
  Supplied 64 items to be assigned to group 1 of size 7 in column 'y'. The RHS length must either be 1 (single values are ok) or match the LHS length exactly. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() explicitly to make this intent clear to readers of your code.
```

3. then I tried to create y at first and replace top2 in each group by `NA`.

But the result of

```
score$y<-ifelse((lag(score$NI,1)<0 &lag(score$NI,2)<0),1,0)
score %>%
       group_by(CONM)%>%
       select(y)%>%
       replace(top_n(2),NA)
```

is this error:

> Adding missing grouping variables: `CONM` Error in
> tbl_vars_dispatch(x) : object 'y' not found

Could someone give me some idea about this? Thank you.

This is my current result and data:

```
COMN     NI     y
A        1      NA
A        2      NA
A        3      0
B        -4     0
B        -5     0
B        6      1
```

Comment: In your first approach try `mutate(y=ifelse((lag(NI,1)<0 & lag(NI,2) <0), 1, 0))%>%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear to me exactly what result you're looking for but your first approach seems to have two issues.

First, the `$` inside `mutate` doesn't work that way.  You can just call the column name (`NI`) directly, without the dataframe name.  Fixing this will allow your code to run.

```
score %>%
  group_by(COMN) %>%
  mutate(y = ifelse((
    lag(NI, 1) < 0 & lag(NI, 2) < 0
  ), 1, 0)) %>%
  ungroup()

  COMN     NI     y
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         1    NA
2 A         2     0
3 A         3     0
4 B        -4    NA
5 B        -5    NA
6 B         6     1
```

Second, and pertaining to the `NA`s in `y`: with `lag` you can set the `default` variable to tell the function what you want it to evaluate non-existent values as.  In your code you're looking for values lagging a given row by 1 or 2, which means those values are undefined for row 1, and row 1 and row 2 of each group respectively.

The code below will evaluate non-existent values as `1` and so won't give you `NA`s in `y`, but again it's unclear what your desired output is.

```
score %>%
  group_by(COMN) %>%
  mutate(y = ifelse((
    lag(NI, 1, default = 1) < 0 & lag(NI, 2, default = 1) < 0
  ), 1, 0)) %>%
  ungroup()

  COMN     NI     y
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         1     0
2 A         2     0
3 A         3     0
4 B        -4     0
5 B        -5     0
6 B         6     1
```

Comment: And a quick question, could we use replace with dplyr and group_by?

Comment: Speaking generally you can use `replace` together with `dplyr` functions including `group_by`.  If you have a specific issue in mind you can ask a new question about it.

Comment: sure. understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `data.table` solution. Just remove `score$` from the `lag(.)` functions, with it the grouping will no longer be effective.
And I have coerced to integer, not used `ifelse`.

```
library(data.table)

score[, y := as.integer(lag(NI, 1) < 0 & lag(NI, 2) < 0), by = COMN]
score
#   COMN NI  y
#1:    A  1 NA
#2:    A  2  0
#3:    A  3  0
#4:    B -4 NA
#5:    B -5 NA
#6:    B  6  1
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply! A quick question, how could this work? how could it know I assign 0 if meet the condition and 1 otherwise? what if I want to assign 2 if meet and 3 otherwise?

Comment: @ling That could be solved with simple logic and arithmetics. `FALSE/TRUE` is integers `0/1`. To reverse, `as.integer(!condition)` and to scale up, add a constant to the condition, this doesn't even need `as.integer`, to add `num + logical` becomes a number.

Comment: Make sense. Thank you!